# jQuery mobile datebox does not work on cordova

Tags: cordova, datebox

I am building an mobile app with cordova and I wanted to use the following date picker.

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/

I tried it first on my computer and it worked. The date picker opened when I clicked on the calendar symbol on the right side of the text field.

Now in my cordova app, when I tried the same, it did show the same form, but the date picker does not open when I touch on the calendar symbol.

When I turn on "useFocus", I can click anywhere to open the date picker, not only on the symbol. That works on my pc, but not in my cordova app.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Are you waiting for the `deviceready` event?